# Pac4j 6 SAML2Configuration.setServiceProviderMetadataPath is mandatory for SAML SSO configuration?

Tags: pac4j

I have updated the software to `pack4j` version 6 with play framework 2.9 + sbt 2.13.

system complaining about `setServiceProviderMetadataPath`  is missing for SAML SSO
this property was not used for `pack4j` version 5. SSO work with out metadata data XML path

is there a flag to disable ?